# FBSDKAppInviteDialog Always Presents a Logged Out Web View

Tags: ios, facebook

When I present a `FBSDKAppInviteContent` via `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`. A web view is presented telling the user to login.

The documentation [website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview) mentions: "Facebook Login is not required for app invites because the experience takes place in the Facebook native mobile app. As a result, you should check to make sure this feature is available and hide the flow if it isn't."

- I have the native app installed
- I have all the required `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` (fbapi, fb-messenger-api, fbauth2 and fbshareextension)
- I have the correct URL scheme added `fbxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I can login using the website and send the invites perfectly fine, however if inviting via the native app would be much preferred as having to get the user to type in their password is a bit of a pain.

[Screenshot of screen I'm shown when presenting FBSDKAppInviteDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyMly.png)

Comment: Ensure you describe what the screenshot at the bottom is for?

Comment: @pal4life done!

Comment: So what kind of view are you looking for incase you can include a link or screenshot to that ?